Fluid pressure and wall stiffness
I come from a medical background, but this is what I understand about the origin of fluid pressure. Please correct me, if I am wrong about this.
Fluids especially liquids, have pressure virtue of the walls of the container(be it a bottle, balloon), constraining the molecules and forcing them to remain a bit compressed, thus giving rise to static pressure.
So, the fluid molecules tend to expand outwards and the elasticity of the container, prevents them from expanding to their natural resting position.
I have a doubt regarding the transfer of energy between the fluid contained and the walls of the container.
Let us assume, I have x molecules of a liquid(assuming its mostly incompressible, contained in a rigid steel vessel, now keeping everything the same(temperature etc), I just change the walls of the vessel to a very compliant rubbery material. At a molecular level when I do this, the springs between the fluid particles, which were relatively more compressed, free up a bit and the intermolecular distance reduces a wee bit, lowering the internal pressure, the pressure difference probably goes in deflecting the vessel wall and is stored as elastic energy(Conservation of total energy)
So the material of the wall in other words, determines the degree of compression and deflection of the wall(at a molecular level) and hence the partition of energy between the pressure energy of fluid contained and the elastic potential energy of the wall.
Does this make intuitive sense? Please correct me if I am wrong, I have struggled with this concept for sometime


A broad and useful framework to predict what does occur in this context (as opposed to what could occur through energy conservation alone, the First Law of Thermodynamics) is minimization of a relevant energy, a consequence of the Second Law of Thermodynamics.
Mathematically, this means taking the derivative of that energy with respect to the extent of any process that can occur (quantified by, e.g., a displacement or reaction coordinate) and setting that derivative to zero. This—along with the second derivative being positive, to ensure that the minimum is being identified—defines the equilibrium outcome.
This often has a simple interpretation: Forces balance. That framework is equivalent because forces are derivatives of energy with respect to displacements, so opposing forces equaling each other matches differentiating the total energy and setting the result to zero. Which framework is easier to intuit or analyze depends on the problem.
So what is the correct energy to take? In this case, one might explore adding up, say,

the gravitational potential energy of the water and container walls (integrating $\rho g h\,dV$, with local density $\rho$ of an infinitesimal element, gravitational acceleration $g$, local height $h$ of the element, and differential volume $dV$),
the surface energy of the water (integrating $s\,dA$, with local surface tension or interface energy penalty $s$ and differential area $dA$), and
the strain energy within the water and container walls (under a linear-elasticity assumption of slight deformation, integrating $\boldsymbol\sigma\boldsymbol\varepsilon\,dV = \frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{C\varepsilon}^2\,dV$, with local stress $\boldsymbol\sigma$, local strain $\boldsymbol\varepsilon$, and stiffness $\boldsymbol C$, all generally tensors).

Other terms could be added to represent additional nuances, or some (such as the surface energy) could be ignored if they're insignificant relative to the others. If the liquid can be considered incompressible, one could replace its gravitational potential energy with $mg\bar h$, with liquid mass $m$ and center-of-mass height $\bar h$. In a liquid under only slight compression (i.e., essentially constant volume $V$), the strain energy is essentially $\frac{1}{2}KV\varepsilon^2$, with bulk modulus $K$; the stress and strain tensors have simplified to represent pressure and volumetric strain $\varepsilon$ alone, as fluids can't sustain a shear stress. In a gas, the isothermal bulk modulus is more or less its pressure, exactly so for the ideal gas.
If some change can be envisioned that monotonically lowers the total energy, it is spontaneous. (Alternatively, in the force framework, a net force acting on an object tends to move it.) Equilibrium corresponds to a slight rearrangement always increasing the total energy; some energy component terms may decrease—referred to as an energy benefit below—but others increase by a greater amount, referred to as an energy penalty below. (An example of the latter is progressive deformation of an elastic object, where the stored strain energy increases with the square of the deformation.)
Example: For a liquid floating in zero gravity (surrounded by its equilibrium vapor pressure to preclude evaporation), without a container, the surface shape minimizes to a sphere with size such that any tighter squeezing would incur a strain energy penalty greater than the surface energy benefit.
Example: For a liquid in a rigid container in a gravity field, a pressure and density gradient arises wherein the liquid compresses until the strain energy penalty matches the gravitational potential benefit of allowing liquid above it to be lower.
Example: A mixture of gases in a gravity field (or a centrifuge) exhibits enrichment of the heavier gases.
Example: To finally address your question, upon replacing the rigid container with a flexible container, the container expands and sags until the strain energy penalty of further container deformation becomes as large as (again) the energetic payoff of the liquid moving lower. As mentioned above, deformation stores energy quadratically, but losing height releases energy only linearly. At some point, these changes exactly counteract. In the force framework, deformation of the container wall stops when the outward force applied by the liquid's pressure balances the inward force applied by the wall's hoop stress, for instance. Again, it may be easier depending on the circumstances to perform analysis by either balancing forces at different regions or to write an expression for the total energy and to minimize it.
Why is energy minimization arguably more useful than energy conservation here? For systems in thermal contact with their surroundings, a spontaneous process typically causes heat transfer between the system and the surroundings, and a conservation-of-energy analysis would require this heating to be tracked and incorporated. If you hang a weight on a spring (potential energy $-mgx$, spring constant $k$), for example, the weight will oscillate, and the motion will be damped out to stop at the equilibrium position $\frac{mg}{k}$ below, storing energy $\frac{1}{2}kx^2 = \frac{mgx}{2}$ in the spring. Fully half the original energy has been lost to friction! Energy minimization avoids the need to consider this heating; indeed, minimization of the total gravitational and strain energy $-mgx+\frac{1}{2}kx^2$ gives the spring relation $x=-\frac{mg}{k}$. With this simple example, a force balance is enough, but the broader framework described in this answer provides an alternate way to handle more complex container wall deformations in the original problem, which involves not uniaxial stretching but perhaps biaxial stretching, bending, and shear.

Thank you for your reply. I was hoping for a bit more intuitive explanation. I understand the total energies you mentioned and total energy conservation. Wrt to the question, do you mean that on replacing the wall, some of the strain energy(pressure energy of fluid) will trade off with the energy stored in the deformation of the wall?

If you can put this line, “ the container expands and sags until the strain energy penalty of further container deformation becomes as large as (again) the energetic payoff of the liquid moving lower.” in a bit simpler manner, for someone who is actively not doing physics currently

Sure; please see the edited answer, and let me know if anything's unclear.

Thank you! I understand what you mean by strain energy penalty and energy benefit. You have incorporated gravitational potential energy as well, and then tried to redistribute energy stored as gravitational energy and the deformation of the container wall(one being linear, other being quadratically, till a new equilibrium is reached, right?

What if we ignore gravitational effects and just talk about the strain energy of liquid(the fact that springs between the liquid molecules are compressed slightly) and the deformation of the wall of the container. Now if the wall becomes compliant, it expands and bit and the springs release some of their energy. Keeping other parameters constant, will that lower internal pressure? Can I do a qualitative trade off between energy stored as deformation in elastic wall and the potential energy in springs inside the liquid?

So just instead of this line(because I am not focusing on gravitational component), can I say upon replacing the rigid container with a flexible container, the container expands and sags until the strain energy penalty of further container deformation becomes as large as (again) the energetic payoff of the liquid molecules slightly unwinding/restoring the springs between them to their natural resting position(strain energy vs elastic energy of wall)

Well, bonds aren't inherently compressed (unless something is compressing them). Left alone, they sit at an equilibrium position that balances attractive and repulsive tendencies. Now, if a liquid is compressed by being constrained to higher than its normal density within a flexible container, then the equilibrium is set by the topics discussed above: An increase (decrease) in volume would force more strain energy to be stored in the container than relieved in the liquid, and vice versa. Does this answer your question?

Thank you for your reply. Yes, from what I understand, liquid pressure is dictated by the imaginary springs being compressed a bit(at an atomic level) by the walls of the container or whatever device/object is restraining the liquid eg balloon, blood vessel etc. And intuitively, a change in wall stiffness, will cause the said energy redistribution, wherein, some of the energy stored as strain energy is released to the deformation energy of the wall

So, if I have blood stored in a closed vessel, with a particular wall tension, if I were to change the wall tension by contracting or relaxing the smooth muscle lining the vessel, the stiffness of the vessel will change and that should have a corresponding effect on the internal pressure of blood, similar to what we discussed, with energy partitioning between the inner contents and vessel wall.
